# TS) How to format an array to match the type/interface of an external component?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

So I am using a treeview library in react which takes an array of a built-in type NodeModule[]. The array I give to the tree component is being used in another component in a different format (with different key names). I changed the data (see "thirdTreeData") as below so that its objects have the same key names as NodeModule[]. But I get an error:

**Argument of type** '{ id: number; parent: number | null; text: string; }[] | undefined' **is not assignable to parameter of type** 'NodeModel[] | (() => NodeModel[])'.

What NodeModule[] looks like:

```
export declare type NodeModel<T = unknown> = {
 id: number | string;
 parent: number | string;
 text: string;
 };
```

How I changed it to match with the type NodeModule[]. (I renamed parent_id to parent and name to text)

```
const thirdTreeData = secondTreeData?.map(tree => {
return { id: tree.id, parent: tree.parent_id,  text: tree.name };
 });
```

This is what I see when I hover thirdTreeData,

```
const thirdTreeData: {
id: number;
parent: number | null;
text: string;
 }[] | undefined
```

(*secondTreeData's type is - const secondTreeData: ITree[] | undefined )

How do I turn its type to NodeModule[] so that I can pass in thirdTreeData successfully into the tree component as below?

```
const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState<NodeModel[]>(thirdTreeData);
```

I get the error above.

What I've tried: I tried putting : NodeModule[] in front of thirdTreeData but this didn't work :(

```
 const thirdTreeData :NodeModule[] = secondTreeData?.map(tree =>
```

I'm new to typescript so thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

okay i think i figured it out.. to satisfy the type of `NodeModel[]`, I had to pass in `|| 0` for 'parent' so that it becomes a **number** when `tree.parent_id` is **null**.

Also to make sure that `thirdTreeData` does not take 'undefined', I used a ternary to pass in an empty array when `secondTreeData` is undefined!

```
const thirdTreeData: NodeModel[] = secondTreeData
? secondTreeData.map(tree => {
  return { id: tree.id, parent: tree.parent_id || 0,  text: tree.name };
  })
: [];
```

Comment: Good job in finding a solution by yourself and sharing it! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the `thirdTreeData` doesn't satisfy the `NodeModel` type, so you can simply fix that by saying that `parent` property should be `number` or `null` and `id` a `number` in `NodeModel` type as the following code snippet::

```
 export declare type NodeModel<T = unknown> = {
     id: number; // <-- id should be a number
     parent: number | null; // <-- parent number or null
     text: string;
 };
```

The `treeData` state generic should be `NodeModel[]` or `undefined` though:

```
const [treeData, setTreeData] = useState<NodeModel[] | undefined>(thirdTreeData);
```

Hope that works.

Comment: OP probably means that `NodeModel` is from a 3rd party library, so they have to adapt to it, they cannot change it.

Comment: @ghybs yes that's right.. but I finally figured it out and posted the solution. 
@ Alexandre Costa thank you for sharing your answer though!!